# Spring Boot Test Mock a service method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

How Can I mock the dep object without considering the internal logic of `getDepartmetdDetails`:

```
   @Service
   public class StudentService {
     @Autowired private DepartmentService departmentService;
    
    public List<Student> getDetails(String departmentId, int page, int size) {
     .....
      Department dep = departmentService.getDepartmetdDetails(departmentId);
    
    }
    ...........
  }
```

My tests are as follows.

```
 @SpringBootTest
   @EnableAutoConfiguration(
    exclude = {
      MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
      MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
      MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class
    })
@AutoConfigureJsonTesters
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("unit-test")
public class StudentTest {
     @InjectMocks
     public DepartmentService departmentService;
    
     @Test
     void whengetDetails() throws Exception {
        String departmentId = "departmentId";
        .....

         when(departmentService.getDepartmetdDetails(departmentId))
                .thenReturn(department);
     }
}
```

Here it will go inside the `getDepartmetdDetails` method in `departmentService`. I need to mock the result returning from the `getDepartmetdDetails` without going inside the method.

Comment: Change InjectMocks to Mock annotation.

Comment: Replace `@InjectMocks` with `@MockBean`. That way Spring Boot will create a mock and use it instead of the real `DepartmentService`.

Comment: I changed the InjectMocks to MockBeans. Now it is working as expected.